# Multiple RNN in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to use a 2 deep layer RNN without MultiRNNCell in TensorFlow, I mean using the output of the 1layer as the input of the 2layer as:

```
cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_filters, state_is_tuple=True)
rnn_outputs1, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell1, inputs, dtype = tf.float32)
cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_filters, state_is_tuple=True)
rnn_outputs2, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell2, rnn_outputs1, dtype = tf.float32)
```

but I get the following error: "Attempt to have a second RNNCell use the weights of a variable scope that already has weights"
I don't want to reuse the weights of the cell1 in the cell2, I want two differents layers because I need the outputs of each layer. How can I do it?

Comment: Would you mind adding the definitions of `inputs` and `rnn_outputs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the construction of your `rnn` into 2 different variable scopes to ensure they use different internal variables.

E.g. by doing it explicitly

```
cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_filters, state_is_tuple=True)
with tf.variable_scope("rnn1"):
    rnn_outputs1, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell1, inputs, dtype = tf.float32)
cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_filters, state_is_tuple=True)
with tf.variable_scope("rnn2"):
    rnn_outputs2, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell2, rnn_outputs1, dtype = tf.float32)
```

or by using the `scope` argument of the `dynamic_rnn` method:

```
cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_filters, state_is_tuple=True)
rnn_outputs1, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell1, inputs, dtype=tf.float32, scope='rnn1')
cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_filters, state_is_tuple=True)
rnn_outputs2, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell2, rnn_outputs1, dtype=tf.float32, scope='rnn2')
```